# como hacer una matriz que me ordene por apellido y edad en python en la misma base de datos

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from google.colab import files 
uploaded = files.upload()
file = open('archivo1.txt','r') 

def Datos(file):
    for i in file.readlines():
        print (i)
        file.close
    return Datos
archivo=open ("archivo1.txt","r")

def desplagar(proyecto):
  for i in proyecto.readlines():
      print (i)
      proyecto.close
  return desplegar

def Matriz(proyecto):
    proyecto=open("archivo1.txt","r")
    C=[]
    for linea in proyecto.readlines():
        if linea!="/n":
           C=C+[linea]
    return C

New_matrix= Matriz(archivo)
def Count(New_matrix):
  New_matrix = Matriz(archivo)
  mat = []
  mat2 = []

  for i in range(len(New_matrix)):
    divide = New_matrix[i].split()
    mat = mat + [divide]

  for j in range(len(mat)):
    elemento = mat[j][2]
    mat2 = mat2 + [elemento]

  return mat2

  apellido=Count(New_matrix)
  apellido.sort(key=str.lower)
apellido
def count(nmatrix):
  nmatrix=Matriz(archivo)
  m=[]
  m2=[]
  for i in range(len(nmatrix)):
    div=nmatrix[i].split()
    m=m+[div]
  for j in range(len(m)):
    el=m[j][4]
    m2=m2+[el]
  return m2
edad=count(nmatrix)
edad.sort()
edad
```

pd.la matriz tiene que estar ordenada

*Diseñar un programa para construir una base de datos, en forma de una matriz bi-dimensional a partir de la
información contenida en el archivo de texto (previamente realizada). Tendrás que investigar cómo leer un
archivo de texto en python. Una vez que puedas leer el archivo y hayas construido la matriz, se pide que el
programa permita al usuario elegir una de las siguientes opciones:
i) Desplegar la base de datos.
ii) Ordenar la base de datos por apellido y edad.
iii) Calcular los siguientes datos:
i. número de Hombres y Mujeres
ii. promedio de edad por sexo
iii. número de personas por género de película según sexo.